# what is the most optimal way to get current iteration count while iterating a dict in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the most optimal way to achieve th following functionality:

```
i= 0
imagesdict = dict()
for image in list(glance.images.list()):
    d = image._info
    imagesdict[i] = d
    i=i+1
return json.dumps(imagesdict)
```

Comment: `for i, image in enumerate(glance.images.list())`? Did you Google this first?

Comment: Apologies. I am new to python. hence I don't know what exactly I should be searching for.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the current index in the iterable while iterating it, like this

```
for i, image in enumerate(glance.images.list()):
    imagesdict[i] = image._info
```

Even better, you can use dictionary comprehension, like this

```
json.dump({i: image._info for i, image in enumerate(glance.images.list())})
```

Comment: btw, `enumerate()` can take a *start* argument, so the first value can be 1 (or whatever).  `enumerate(items, start=1)`

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bit odd -- why are you creating a dictionary if you're making all the keys ints? Why not just use a list and index each element?

Regardless, you can compact this using dictionary comprehensions:

```
imagesdict = {i: image._info for i, image in enumerate(glance.images.list())}
```

What the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function does is takes in a list, and returns a new one that bundles the index with it. So, if I do `enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c'])`, the output will be `[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]`.

So, once we do `enumerate(glance.images.list())`, the next step is to turn that into an actual dictionary. You can do that using either a normal for loop, or even better, a dictionary comprehension to get the final dict in one line.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list instead of a dict here:

```
json.dumps([image._info for image in glance.images.list()])
```

If you can't change the output format if it is consumed by the code that is outside of your control then to get a json object that communicates the same information:

```
json.dumps(dict(enumerate(image._info for image in glance.images.list())))
```